# Makefile - run time decisions using ifeq

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to solve a particular problem where variables are assigned in one recipe and then interpreted in other recipes, all during run time. As I understand it, ifeq conditions are evaluated during parsing which doesn't work for me as some of them are always false. Is there a way to implement what I'm trying to do (expected output is below)? I'll provide more info if needed.

I'm using make version 3.81 on Linux Mint 17.1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
fourth =

all: check valueOfFourth definitionOfFourth
.PHONY: all

check:
    @echo "TEST"$(cnt)
ifeq ($(first),$(second))
    @echo "1. First condition"
    $(eval fourth = "first")
else ifeq ($(first),$(third))
    @echo "1. Second condition"
    $(eval fourth = "second")
else
    @echo "1. Conditions weren't met"
endif

valueOfFourth:
ifeq ($(fourth),"first")
    @echo "2. First"
else ifeq ($(fourth),"second")
    @echo "2. Second"
else
    @echo "2."
endif

definitionOfFourth:
ifeq ($(fourth),)
    @echo "3. Variable is not defined"
else
    @echo "3. Variable is defined"
endif
```

It is invoked like this:

```
make cnt="1" first="x" second="x" third="y" && printf "\n" && \
make cnt="2" first="x" second="y" third="x" && printf "\n" && \
make cnt="3" first="x" second="y" third="z"
```

Expected output:

```
TEST1
1. First condition
2. First
3. Variable is defined

TEST2
1. Second condition
2. Second
3. Variable is defined

TEST3
1. Conditions weren't met
2. 
3. Variable is not defined
```

Actual output:

```
TEST1
1. First condition
2. 
3. Variable is not defined

TEST2
1. Second condition
2. 
3. Variable is not defined

TEST3
1. Conditions weren't met
2. 
3. Variable is not defined
```

It is evident that only the "check" target does what it is supposed to do, the other two simply do not work.

Comment: Why are you trying to do things this way? What problem are you trying to solve with this? Does using target-specific variable assignments (which apply to all the target's prerequisites) help you here?

Comment: @EtanReisner These are just exercises given to us by the professor. I, myself, am completely new to make in general. This one doesn't have much to do with building the source code, it's just playing with variables and control flow. The instructions aren't very clear which certainly doesn't help.

Comment: The exercise was to get this to work with make as written here? Or, more generally, to use conditionals in make to affect what happens via the make process?

Comment: Not to get this to work as written (that's what I wrote trying to solve this) but to get the expected output by using ifeq, variables, phony targets and such.

Comment: Are you given specific phony targets or make command lines you need to support to do this?

Comment: Those three targets are required and the usage of ifeq is also required. Nothing else as far as I can tell.

Comment: Pull the conditional setting logic out to the toplevel and just print as appropriate from each target?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Could you post actual code, if it's not a problem?

Comment: Wouldn't that be statically defining values? They need to be dynamically resolved in order to get the required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely clear how these targets are supposed to interact (any interaction between them is generally a bad idea as parallel make execution means that without being explicitly sequenced via prerequisites between them execution order is not guaranteed). But assuming non-parallel make and that each target is supposed to output one of the lines of output I believe this does what you want.

```
.PHONY: all
all: check valueOfFourth definitionOfFourth

ifeq ($(first),$(second))
    fourth = First
    condmsg = $(fourth) condition
else ifeq ($(first),$(third))
    fourth = Second
    condmsg = $(fourth) condition
else
    condmsg = Conditions weren'\''t met
endif

check:
    @echo 'TEST$(cnt)'
    @echo '1. $(condmsg)'

valueOfFourth:
    @echo '2. $(fourth)'

definitionOfFourth:
ifeq ($(fourth),)
    @echo "3. Variable is not defined"
else
    @echo "3. Variable is defined"
endif
```

Comment: That's not what I get here. I just copied and pasted this makefile  (edited for leading tabs in the targets) and your commands from the OP and got your expected output. With multiple different versions of make. Make sure you copied the makefile correctly. `md5sum Makefile` -> `290fb1651f4c9257908d988c6295d585`.

Comment: You could try uploading it to a file-hosting service because a simple C/P results in spaces instead of tabs so the make parser gets a bit angry. I had to change those - the hash won't certainly be the same.

Comment: The hash is of the tabified file. The literal file I ran make on and got your output. you should be able to space-to-tab the copied and pasted file and get a file with the same sum. That's why I said I edited for leading tabs after pasting and listed the sum. Only five lines need editing. `sed -e '15,16s/^\s\+/\t/;19s/^\s\+/\t/;23,25s/^\s\+/\t/'` No trailing spaces, no blank lines at the end, etc.